# Where did my Minecraft Screenshots go?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

While I was playing Minecraft, I pressed F2 to take some screenshots, then when I logged off of Minecraft, and checked my Minecraft file to see my screenshots, they weren't there, so then I went back to Minecraft, went on a world, took a screenshot, then logged off again to check the folder that had all the screenshots again. And when I looked, the screenshot I had just taken was not there. So I have no idea what happened to the screenshots can you guys help me out and tell me how to find the screenshots or if their delayed.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into `Options > Resource Packs...` and click on `Open Resource Pack Folder`, it will take you to `.../.minecraft/resourcepacks`. Navigate up one directory and then into `.../.minecraft/screenshots`. They are saved there.

This is `%AppData%/.minecraft/screenshots` on Windows and `~/.minecraft/screenshots` on Linux. I'm not sure about Mac.